# How do I install the Jetspeed Maven plugin if .m2 file is read-only?

Tags: apache2, maven-3

I am currently trying to go through the Jetspeed portal [tutorial](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/tutorial/index.html). However, once I made it to the "Configure Maven Build" section, I ran into a problem.

The tutorial asks that in order to setup the Jetspeed Maven plugin, I edit a file called `settings.xml` in the `.m2` folder.

However, I do not have a visible .m2 folder in my home directory. I can point to `home/ryan/.m2` in the terminal, but it simply has a repository file (and, again, this is all unseen within the file explorer).

I located the settings.xml file and a file called `m2.conf` in `/usr/share/maven/conf` directory, but both these files are read-only.

Additionally, the tutorial says to create a .m2 folder in your home directory if there isn't one present, but when I try to do this, I'm given an error that such a file already exists.

I'm really at a loss here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hit Ctrl + H. To see hidden files in the file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, when a folder (and I believe files as well) have a period before the name, they are "hidden". You can't see them unless you do what MadMike said, unhide them via `Ctrl`+`H`.

This is done because these folders often hold lots of configuration files and stuff the non-regular user wouldn't need to mess with, so they are hidden to make a cleaner view.

So, the folder is actually there. As for getting read/write access, just enter the commands `sudo chmod +rwx [FILES]`. It will give you read, write, and execute permissions on those files. However, be careful, as messing around with `sudo` and `chmod`/`chown` can *really* mess up your system in case you allow yourself to do something dangerous you otherwise wouldn't have been able to.